# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string when trying to read Json with a path that contains number

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I am trying to return a JSON array like so:

```
jsarr = new JSONArray(JSON.read(genericPathComp).toString());
```

Where genericPathComp is a compiled JSON path.

This approach works fine, but when my JSON path contains a number, the folloling exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ustomerAccountBalance,billingAccount[(-1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.filter.ArrayIndexFilter.filter(ArrayIndexFilter.java:75)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.filter.PathTokenFilter.filter(PathTokenFilter.java:50)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:255)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonReader.read(JsonReader.java:103)
    at dataAnalytics.ValidateAttributes.responseParser(ValidateAttributes.java:174)
    at dataGeneration.Main.main(Main.java:76)
```

The JSON path the throws this exception is:
$.parts[customerAccountBalance,billingAccount[-1:]]

I don't understand why it is parsing an int, what am I missing?

EDIT: I am using jayway parser and the variable JSON is a ReadContext variable. So it is a handle to a valid JSON. So far this code works for every JSON path that does not have a number in it. So for example $.parts.billingAccount and $.name.date all work.

The original JSON looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": [
      {
        "value": "John"
      }
    ],
    "parts": {
      "customerAccountBalance": [
        {
          "amount": "1"
        }
      ],
      "billingAccount": [
        {
          "type": "example"
        },
        {
          "date": "also example"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And I would like to return an array that consists of the that last array of billing account and all of customer account balance.

Comment: "For input string: "ustomerAccountBalance,billingAccount[(-1"" means there's something wrong with your genericPathComp variable. Try debugging and checking if it's what you want it to be

Comment: After compilation, the variable is still $.parts[customerAccountBalance,billingAccount[-1:]]. When I try with other JSON paths that have numbers in them, the exception follows a similar pattern; the original JSON path is cut just after the number in the stack trace.

Comment: What's `JSON.read(genericPathComp)`? I'm not aware of a class named `JSON` in jayway jsonpath. The idiom is `JsonPath.parse(someJson).read(jsonPath);` so perhaps JSON in your question is a handle to a DocumentContext? Too much guessing here ;) Perhaps you could post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: * What JSON library are you using?
* Can you give an example of a `genericPathComp` that works and one that doesn't?

Comment: See edits please

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to read? Providing a sample of the original JSON and the desired output would be very useful here. The given jsonPath looks invalid to me (I suspect you might want something like `$.parts.customerAccountBalance.billingAccount[-1:]`) but without knowing (a) the structure of the JSON and (b) your desired output it's difficult to offer a solution.

Comment: See the edit to view the sample JSON. I need to get an array that consists of the that last array of billing account and all of customer account balance. I am testing the JSON path at jsonpath.com to see if its valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception ...

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ustomerAccountBalance,billingAccount[(-1"
at
```

... is occurring because Jayway is expecting a numeric (`0 - 9`) to follow the opening square bracket. Looking at the [Jayway docs](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) it allows a opening square bracket to be followed by `'` (for bracket-notated children) or `?` (for a filter) and other than that it expects an opening square bracket to be followed by a number.

So, the json path supplied in your question is invalid. I suspect you are trying to read the last `billingAccount` in `parts.customerAccountBalance`. If so then read on ...

Given this JSON:

```
{
  "parts": {
    "customerAccountBalance": {
      "billingAccount": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This json path: `$.parts.customerAccountBalance.billingAccount[-1:]` will return:

```
[
   3
]
```

You can try this yourself using the online [Jayway Evaluator](https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/).

**Update** re this:

> And I would like to return an array that consists of the that last array of billing account and all of customer account balance.

Given this JSON:

```
{
  "Name": [
    {
      "value": "John"
    }
  ],
  "parts": {
    "customerAccountBalance": [
      {
        "amount": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "billingAccount": [
    {
      "type": "example"
    },
    {
      "date": "also example"
    }
  ]
}
```

That involves two read calls:

- "last array of billing account": `$.billingAccount[-1:]`
- "all of customer account balance": `$.parts.customerAccountBalance`

Comment: Thank you for identifying why I was getting the exception. I should have been using this site to test my paths, as opposed to jsonpath.com

I have to figure out how to get what the JSON I want using this parser now

Comment: I have updated the answer to cover this requirement: "I would like to return an array that consists of the that last array of billing account and all of customer account balance".

Comment: The idea was to return it in one array. Perhaps that is not possible with jaway. I will keep trying. Maybe looking at another parser that will be able to do that is a good move. After all, my original JSON path must be valid with some parser if it produced the desired result using jsonpath.com

Comment: That's not possible with JsonPath since each read call evaluates a single json path statemeht. However, in your OP you stated that you are acting upon a parsed context so you've already done the expensive work, invoking read twice on that context is perfectly ok.

Comment: Thanks, I will find a way to implement that.

For the record though, I was trying to figure out if one can get the desired output in a single read call. Using $.parts[customerAccountBalance,billingAccount[-1:]] I was able to get the array: [
  {
    "amount": "1"
  },
  {
    "date": "also example"
  }
]. This is just not possible using the current parser.